# Problema con Scanner con Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de java el cual es para crear una lista de cosas que hacer, mi problema entra cuando ejecuto el programa y entro al case 2, en vez de esperar por mi input regresa al menú principal, cuando cambié el ArrayList por int si funcionó pero no con String, qué debería hacer?

> 

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int seleccion = 0;

    do{
        System.out.println("------To-Do List------");
        System.out.println("1. Ver lista");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir a la lista");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar elemento de la lista");
        System.out.println("4. Salir");
        System.out.print("Digite una opción: ");
        seleccion = sc.nextInt();


        switch (seleccion){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ingrese un elemento: ");
                String elemento = sc.nextLine();
                lista.add(elemento);

                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Digite una opción válida");
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }while(seleccion!=4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se ingresan datos por consola, estos datos se guardan en un espacio de memoria temporal denominado buffer.

Al finalizar de ingresar un dato, se presiona la tecla Enter, la cual también es almacenada en el buffer como un salto de línea ‘\n’, junto con los datos.

El método nextLine ( ) extrae del buffer todos los caracteres que encuentra hasta llegar al Enter, el cual es eliminado del buffer.

Los métodos nextInt ( ) y nextDouble ( ) extraen el dato numérico, lo asignan a la variable, pero dejan el ‘\n’, que es lo único que queda al final en el buffer.

Cuando se invoca nextLine ( ) después de cualquiera de los dos métodos anteriores, lo que ocurre es que como en el buffer hay aún un dato (el ‘\n’), lo procesa inmediatamente como se describió antes, es decir, lee los caracteres hasta encontrar el ‘\n’, pero como ya no hay caracteres antes del ‘\n’, no lee ninguno, a continuación elimina el ‘\n’ y finalmente a la variable se le asigna la cadena vacía.

Una solución, utilizando un único objeto Scanner, es invocar nextLine(); después del ingreso del dato numérico y antes del ingreso de la cadena, para que de esta manera dicha sentencia elimine el ‘\n’ y el buffer quede vacío antes de leer la cadena.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int seleccion = 0;

    do{
        System.out.println("------To-Do List------");
        System.out.println("1. Ver lista");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir a la lista");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar elemento de la lista");
        System.out.println("4. Salir");
        System.out.print("Digite una opción: ");
        seleccion = sc.nextInt();


        switch (seleccion){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Ingrese un elemento: ");
                sc.nextLine();
                String elemento = sc.nextLine();
                lista.add(elemento);

                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Gracias por usar el programa!");
                break;
                default:
              System.out.println("\nDigite una opción válida");
              System.out.println("");
        }
        
    }while(seleccion!=4);
}
```