# ¿Por que si utilizo la variable i del bucle for para imprimir un mensaje segun su valor este me imprime 2 mensajes y no 1?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Estoy diseñando un menú de opciones (soy aprendiz de programador) en la opción (uno) del menú cuando entra en el switch y luego en el for me debería imprimir un solo mensaje por vuelta, pero la primera vez que se ejecuta me imprime 2 mensajes que requieren de dos condiciones para entrar a los if y ejecutarlos, alguien me indica donde está el error en la metodología saludos.

El error empieza en la línea 67 dentro del for.

1. Se pretende realizar un programa para gestionar la lista de participaciones en una competición de salto de longitud.
2. El número de plazas disponible es de 5.
3. Sus datos se irán introduciendo en el mismo orden que vayan inscribiéndose los atletas.
4. Si se selecciona 1, se introducirán los datos de uno de los participantes:

- ```
   - Dorsal, Nombre, mejor marca del 2018, mejor marca del 2019 y mejor marca del 2020.
  ```
- ```
   - Si se elige la opción 2, se debe mostrar un listado por número de dorsal.
  ```
- ```
   - La opción 3 mostrará un listado ordenado por la marca del 2020, de mayor a menor.
  ```

5. Tras procesar cada opción, se debe mostrar de nuevo el menú inicial, hasta que se seleccione la opción 4, que terminará el programa.
6. Diseñar el programa que muestre las siguientes opciones:

- ```
   - Inscribir un participante.
  ```
- ```
   - Mostrar listado de datos.
  ```
- ```
   - Mostrar listado por marcas.
  ```
- ```
   - Finalizar el programa.
  ```

Adjunto codigo

```
introducir el código aquí
import java.util.Scanner;

public class perezSuarezCristoRuben_Actividad_1_05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     *  - La matriz va a tener 5 filas que equivalen a la cantidad de participantes máxima.
     *  - La matriz tendrá 5 columnas porque es la cantidad de datos mínima y máxima a almacenar.
     */
    String [][] datosParticipantes = new String [5][5];

    // Esta variable almacenará los datos de cada usuario y los ira trasladando a las posiciones correspondientes de la matriz según la toma de requisitos.
    String datos = "";

    // Esta variable controlara que opción del menú del programa se ejecutara.
    int opcionMenu = 0;

    /*
     *  - Si el usuario presiona 4 el valor de la variable cambiara de false a true.
     *  - El bucle while dejara de ejecutar las instrucciones por lo cual el programa dejara de ejecutarse.
     */
    boolean cerrarPrograma = false;

    // Esta variable ira sumando 1 cada vez que se introduzca un usuario para controlar que filas y columnas de la matriz se rellenan.
    int contadorUsuarios = 1;

    /*
     *  - Este bucle controlara la condición de salida del programa que dependiendo de si el usuario pulsa un 4 saldrá del menú o no y finalizara el programa.
     *  - Será de tipo while porque no sabemos cuando el usuario quiere terminar el proceso.
     */
    while (cerrarPrograma == false) {

        // Este bucle controlará que la variable está dentro de los rangos de las opciones para evitar errores futuros en la ejecución del programa.
        do {

            // Indicamos las opciones disponibles y pedimos que introduzca una.
            System.out.println("- Pulse 1 para añadir un participante.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 2 para ver el listado de participante ordenados por dorsal.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 3 para ver un listado ordenado de la marca obtenida por los participantes en el 2020 / 2019 / 2018.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 4 para cerrar el programa.");
                opcionMenu = sc.nextInt();

        } while (opcionMenu < 1 && opcionMenu > 4);
        
        switch (opcionMenu) {
            case 1:
                switch (contadorUsuarios) {
                    case 1:
                        for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++)    {
                            
                            if (i == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del primer participante:");
                            }

                            if (i == 1) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del primer participante:");
                            }

                            if (i == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del primer participante:");
                            }

                            if (i == 3) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del primer participante:");
                            }

                            if (i == 4) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del primer participante:");
                            }

                            datos = sc.nextLine();
                            datosParticipantes [0][i] = datos;

                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length; j++)    {

                            if (j == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del segundo participante:");
                            }

                            if (j == 1) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del segundo participante:");
                            }

                            if (j == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del segundo participante:");
                            }

                            if (j == 3) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del segundo participante:");
                            }

                            if (j == 4) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del segundo participante:");
                            }

                            datos = sc.nextLine();
                            datosParticipantes [1][j] = datos;

                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < datosParticipantes.length; j2++) {
                            if (j2 == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del tercer participante:");
                            }

                            if (j2 == 1) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del tercer participante:");
                            }

                            if (j2 == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del tercer participante:");
                            }

                            if (j2 == 3) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del tercer participante:");
                            }

                            if (j2 == 4) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del tercer participante:");
                            }

                            datos = sc.nextLine();
                            datosParticipantes [2][j2] = datos;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        for (int k = 0; k < datosParticipantes.length; k++)    {
                            if (k == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del cuarto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k == 1) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del cuarto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del cuarto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k == 3) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del cuarto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k == 4) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del cuarto participante:");
                            }

                            datos = sc.nextLine();
                            datosParticipantes [3][k] = datos;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        for (int k2 = 0; k2 < datosParticipantes.length; k2++) {

                            if (k2 == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dorsal del quinto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k2 == 1) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce el nombre completo del quinto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k2 == 2) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del quinto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k2 == 3) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del quinto participante:");
                            }

                            if (k2 == 4) {
                                System.out.println("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del quinto participante:");
                            }

                            datos = sc.nextLine();
                            datosParticipantes [4][k2] = datos;

                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        System.out.println("La competición solo dispone de 5 plazas no se pueden introducir más usuarios.");
                        break;
                
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                
                break;
            case 3:
                
                break;
            case 4:
                cerrarPrograma = true;
                break;
        
            default:
                break;
        }

        /*
         *
         */
        contadorUsuarios += 1;


       }     
    }    
}
```

Comment: Puede ser porque `datosParticipantes.length` es 10, 5 por cada dimensión...

Comment: Algunas observaciones: puedes unir los `ifs` mediante `else if`. De este modo el procesador verifica condición por condición hasta que una se cumpla. Además puedes volver a usar el nombre `i` para los otros `for`.  Esto por el alcance de las variables.

Comment: despues de `opcionMenu = sc.nextInt();` pon `sc.nextLine()`  [lo que sucede es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509609/problema-con-scanner-con-arraylist/509613#509613)

Comment: Así que lo que había que hacer era vaciar el buffer grande muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque creo que ya te dieron la solución (usar `scanner.nextLine();` para limpiar tu búfer), te dejo una propuesta para que veas cómo mejorar un poco tu código.

1. Evita poner números mágicos (que no sabes de dónde vienen) en cada lugar que lo necesites, como sabes esa es tu constante de número de participantes, define una variable de cuántos participantes y cuántos datos habrá.
2. No necesitas hacer un for para luego comparar uno por uno con ifs, si ya sabes el órden en que los meterán simplemente pon ese código
3. No uses un case para cada participante, si te piden 10, ¿Harás diez casos? ¿Y si te piden 50?, puedes interpolar (realmente es un format) o concatenar strings, entonces define tus números `["primero", "segundo", ..., "enésimo"]`
4. Plantea bien tus ciclos, no es necesario tener un while dentro de otro, mejor usa busca condiciones para terminar tu programa

```java
package stackoverflow.Books;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//      Cuántos participantes quieres (rows) y cuántos datos tiene cada uno (cols)
        int rows = 5, cols = 5;
//      Para evitar poner cada caso, ponemos los números ordinales que interpolaremos en el String
//      Se puede usar con printf o concatenando strings, yo prefiero con printf, pero te dejaré los dos ejemplos
        final String[] numeration = {"primer", "segundo", "tercer", "cuarto", "quinto"};
//      ¿Estás seguro que te conviene que todos sean String? Porque para el 3 será un poco complicado de lograr
        String[][] competitor_data = new String[rows][cols];

        int selected_option;
        boolean add_more = true;
        int user_count = 0;

        do {
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("- Pulse 1 para añadir un participante.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 2 para ver el listado de participante ordenados por dorsal.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 3 para ver un listado ordenado de la marca obtenida por los participantes en el 2020 / 2019 / 2018.");
            System.out.println("- Pulse 4 para cerrar el programa.");
            selected_option = scanner.nextInt();
//          Se usa para limpiar el búfer, pues nextInt deja un salto de línea sin leer 
            scanner.nextLine();
            switch (selected_option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("Introduce el dorsal del %s participante: ", numeration[user_count]);
                    competitor_data[user_count][i++] = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.printf("Introduce el nombre completo del %s participante: ", numeration[user_count]);
                    competitor_data[user_count][i++] = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.printf("Introduce la mejor marca del 2018 del %s participante: ", numeration[user_count]);
                    competitor_data[user_count][i++] = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.printf("Introduce la mejor marca del 2019 del %s participante:", numeration[user_count]);
                    competitor_data[user_count][i++] = scanner.nextLine();
                    //Sería la otra forma de hacerlo
                    System.out.print("Introduce la mejor marca del 2020 del" + numeration[user_count] + "participante:");
                    competitor_data[user_count++][i] = scanner.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(competitor_data));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    add_more = false;
                    break;
            }
//          Mientras quiera seguir añadiendo y el número de usuario sea menor al de las filas
        } while (add_more && user_count < rows);
//      No se te olvide cerrar tu scanner
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```