# Porque me hace un salto de línea en el bucle for

Tags: java

Tengo este bucle, lo que no entiendo es porque me hace un salto de linea:

```
 String[] listaArticulos = new String[3];

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Introduce el titulo del texto");
                    listaArticulos[i] = input.nextLine();
                }
```

Salida de consola usando el método **nextLine()**:

```
Introduce el título del artículo
Introduce el título del artículo

Texto introducido por teclado

Introduce el título del artículo

Texto introducido por teclado
```

Y si pongo el mismo código pero usando **next()**:

```
Introduce el título del artículo

Articulo 1

Introduce el título del artículo

Introduce el título del artículo

Articulo 2
```

Pero si pongo todo el texto junto usando el método next() me muestra las 3 líneas correctamente:

```
Introduce el título del artículo

Articulo1

Introduce el título del artículo

Articulo2

Introduce el título del artículo

Articulo3

Introduce el precio de distribución:
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me salga como la última opción pero pudiendo escribir texto separado?

**Edición de la pregunta:**

Antes del bucle for esta sintaxis está metida dentro de un while para hacer un menu:

```
while(condicion <= 0) {
  Dentro de este while tengo el bucle for...
  String[] listaArticulos = new String[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     System.out.println("Introduce el titulo del artículo");
     listaArticulos[i] = input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Y cuando introduzco el texto por el teclado me muestra esta salida:

```
Introduce el título del artículo
Introduce el título del artículo
Articulo 1 // Este es el texto que yo introduzco
Introduce el título del artículo
Articulo 2 // Este es el texto que yo introduzco
```

Lo que no entiendo es eso: me muestra el primer Introduce el titulo y no me deja escribir, solo me deja escribir a partir del segundo.

Comment: agrega el código completo ,el fragmento que adjuntaste no debería generar la salida que muestras

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código que faltaba @Dramaturgo

Comment: existe un problema común cuando se hace uso de nextDouble() o nexInt() y despues nextLine() en tu caso creo que primero estas usando nexLine() y despues nextDouble() por que en una de tus imagenes veo `Ingrese precio de distribucion` es por eso que te solicite agregar todo el codigo donde hace uso del Scanner.mas detalle de lo mencionado [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509609/problema-con-scanner-con-arraylist/509613#509613)

Answer (score 0):

La primera salida que tienes usando nextLine(), es inválida a no ser que antes de ingresar al ciclo `for` tengas una linea de código: System.out.println("Introduce el titulo del texto"); si no tienes linea de código antes del ciclo `for` no existe ningún error en el fragmento de código que muestras.

En cuanto al uso de `next()`,  lo que realiza es leer la primera palabra ingresada, por ello no te arroja ningún error en la tercera salida que mustras. En la segunda salida que muestras si digitas 2 o más palabras en una misma linea lo que va suceder es que se va guardar cada palabra ingresado en una posición del arreglo que haz declarado (listaArticulos), y cuando tu arreglo tenga más de 3 palabras guardados ya no va almacenar a partir de la 4ta palabra ingresado.

Puedes leer más sobre los métodos [next() y nextLine()](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/java-next-and-nextline/)