# ¿Por qué en el caso 1 del switch me imprime el mensaje, pero no me recoge los datos del teclado ignora la instrucción?

Tags: java, lista, switch

/*

- - Se pretende realizar un programa para gestionar la lista de participaciones en una competición de salto de longitud.
- - El número de plazas disponible es indeterminado.
- - Sus datos se irán introduciendo en el mismo orden que vayan inscribiéndose los atletas.
- - Si se selecciona 1, se introducirán los datos de uno de los participantes:
- ```
   1) Dorsal.
  ```
- ```
   2) Nombre.
  ```
- ```
   3) Mejor marca del 2018.
  ```
- ```
   4) Mejor marca del 2019.
  ```
- ```
   5) Mejor marca del 2020.
  ```
- - Si se elige la opción 2, se debe mostrar un listado por número de dorsal.
- - La opción 3 mostrará un listado ordenado por la marca del 2020, de mayor a menor.
- - Tras procesar cada opción, se debe mostrar de nuevo el menú inicial, hasta que se seleccione la opción 4, que terminará el programa.
- - Diseñar el programa que muestre las siguientes opciones:
- ```
   1) Inscribir un participante.
  ```
- ```
   2) Mostrar listado de datos.
  ```
- ```
   3) Mostrar listado por marcas.
  ```
- ```
   4) Finalizar el programa.
  ```

*/

//Caso 1 del switch, no ejecuta el dorsal.add, he probado a añadirlo a través de una variable simple y tampoco.

```
import java.util.*; public class

perezSuarezCristoRuben_Actividad_01_SP_UT4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 
        Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
        // 
        ArrayList<String> dorsal = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> marca2018 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> marca2019 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> marca2020 = new ArrayList<String>();
        // 
        int opcionMenu = 0;
        // 
        int decisionCerrar = 0;
        // 
        int contadorParticipantes = 0;
        // 
        while (decisionCerrar == 0) {
            // 
            do {
                System.out.println("- Pulse 1 para añadir un participante.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 2 para mostrar los datos de los participantes.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 3 para mostrar un listado de las marcas de cada participante.");
                System.out.println("- Pulse 4 para finalizar el programa.");
                opcionMenu = datos.nextInt();
            } while (opcionMenu < 1 || opcionMenu > 4);
            // 
            System.out.println(" ");
            // 
            switch (opcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Introduzca el dorsal del participante:");
                dorsal.add(datos.nextLine());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    decisionCerrar = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            // 
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Hola Cristo. ¿Has intentado debuggear para comprobar si le llegan valores? Un saludo.

Comment: Una pregunta. A la hora de introducir el dorsal, ¿qué tipo de valores introduces? Igual es necesario hacer un cast de lo ingresado por teclado. Saludos de nuevo.

Comment: dale un vistazo a [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509609/problema-con-scanner-con-arraylist/509613#509613)

Comment: Me funciono tu solución dramaturgo se ve que controlas el tema de vaciar el buffer a mí no se me ocurrió porque solo lo he utilizado para cuando imprimo mensajes pero nunca para cuando recojo datos, me leeré detenida mente la explicación de arriba, en el ciclo superior que realizo no nos han enseñado en que punto vaciar el buffer  así que gracias saludos.

Comment: @CristoPérezSuárez siempre se aprende algo nuevo,saludos